# Which one to choose b/w execute package task and execute process task in ssis

Tags: sql, process, ssis, task, execute

i need a suggestion in choosing between execute package task and execute process task in ssis with its pros and cons.

The requirement is that i need to run the child package from the parent package by passing some of the variables from the parent to child package.i tried using execute package task and also passed the variables to the child package everything works fine.Now i came across a new requirement where i need to pass the configuration file to the child package while calling from parent package. I was not able to do it.So now i am trying to do same using execute process task where the executable i am passing is my child package.Now the problem is that i am unable to read the variables in the parent package and also not able to figure it out how to read the configuration file.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With SSIS 2005/2008 it's more of a pull from the child than a push to it.  You can create the variables that need to be "passed" then use configuration managers to make it available.

This link from msdn should help: [How to: Use the Values of Parent Variables in a Child Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345179.aspx)